# Inline CSS using Jade templating system

Tags: node.js, pug

Is there a way to write inline css using Jade for Node?

My HTML is:

```
<div class="column" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

but I can't see any reference to this in the guides.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write anything you want in HTML attributes:

```
.column(style="align:center;")
```